# Laravel Passport good practices for issuing multiple tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a question about *Laravel Passport* and the best way to manage api access_tokens.

**Currently we have:**

- A token issued by a `grant_type: password` and with no scope:

  ```php
    $data = [
         'grant_type' => 'password',
         'client_id' => $client_id,
         'client_secret' => $client_secret,
         'username' => $user->email,
         'password' => $user->password,
         'scope' => '',
     ];
  ```
- A token for only view a **picture of a user** by creating it like that:

  ```php
  $token = $user->createToken('User Picture token', ['view-picture'])->accessToken;
  ```

The first token issued by the `grant_type: password` will be used only for getting personal user informations.

***Does is it a good practice?***

We want to restrict access to a resource as follows:
A "message" resource that ***contains CRUD actions to its access token*** with a specific scope.

So we want each resource protected **by a different token and a different scope.**

***Does the personal access_token are made for?***

#### EDIT 1:

In order to manage user permissions we use Gates & Policies from Laravel.

Comment: Maybe you can just use a package like [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) for handling permissions in your Laravel app? What do you need the tokens for exactly?

Comment: @DeesOomens thanks for reply, i need tokens for authenticating the user but sometimes the token will be passed to the DOM, like that : `<img src="https://domain/picture?token=eyaehzaoe" />`

Comment: also in our app we already use Gates & Policies from laravel for managing user permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Passport gives you the ability to implemente a full Oauth2 server in a matter of minutes. This means, you can mount a full server to not only manage access to your own apps but for third-party applications.

When I said *"your own apps"* I mean the ones developed by you and/or your team. By *"third-party apps"* I mean the ones that are developed by other developers that have access to your API. Token scopes are a good way to limit the actions this third-party apps can do on behalf of your users.

Take Facebook as an example. If you want to implement access in your app through Facebook, your users will need to allow your app to access to their profile data in order to retrieve their details to effectively log-in in your system.

From the [Passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-scopes):

> ### Token Scopes
>
> Scopes allow your API clients to request a specific set of permissions when requesting authorization to access an account. For example, if you are building an e-commerce application, not all API consumers will need the ability to place orders. Instead, you may allow the consumers to only request authorization to access order shipment statuses. In other words, **scopes allow your application's users to limit the actions a third-party application can perform on their behalf**.

Now, if your API is gonna be consumed just by your apps, I mean, if you are not going to expose or make public your API blueprint to anyone but your team, you can just authorize users with roles and permissions and/or implement Laravel Gates/Policies.

Then you can just identify the user by the token and check if the user has the right permission/role to make a specific action or access to some data (or parts of it).

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i as said i think it can be dangerous to have only one token because i need to pass the token in the DOM like : `<img src="https://example.com/picture?token=aert />`, so do you think create a token only for picture ressource is a good practice?

Comment: That's the thing. You shouldn't be worried if the user access your token or not. At the end of the day, the token is your way to identify him/her, so they can make what the want if they are allowed. If the user has a limited access to the data you can check in the backend to see if they can access.

Comment: You are not gonna generate a different token for each scope the user might request to access. The token itself has -encoded- the user identifier and also the permissions he/she has (scopes). What Passport do is to check if your specified requestes scopes (`'scope' => 'access-image',`) is included in the user encoded token.

Comment: In my team Laravel Passport is only used in internal with an WebApp, and mobile applications, but actually the token generated by the `grant_type: password` are wide open.

Comment: So i thought that multiple token for access other ressources : `{"picture_token": "", "message_token": ""}` and so on,  message_token have the scope `'scope' => 'access-message'`

Comment: so if i understand correctly, the front-end will call `POST /oauth/personal-access-tokens` and passing the scope?